# Azure website deployment: routing behavior not the same as localhost tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

The problem I was initially trying to solve is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35068513/831138).

**tl;dr**: multilingual website, redirecting to translated .cshtml views depending on the language.

Azure was treating the view re-routing differently in the case of Home/Index, so I made patch to solve that (see own-answer in previous post).

**Current problem**: I thought it was solved, but it was just because the css was cached. Now it is a mess, that is to say: the routing of the css elements seems to have changed after deploying to Azure. Again: this can not be reproduced in localhost.

Anybody has any idea about how to deal with this seemingly undebuggable differences between localhost tests and Azure?

Comment: Do you use bundles? Are the CSS files not retrieved at all or are the URLs in the CSS files wrong?

Comment: @Markus These are the console errors after deployment: http://i.imgur.com/WSPSqkM.png .

Comment: The errors might be related to bundling. The bad thing is, that bundles are usually disabled when debugging so that errors will appear only in a release build. In order to activate bundling also in the debug version, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16030958/642579 This should help in finding the reason.